# NetEase Cloud Music: Getting search results in API

Tags: websites, api

I'm trying to make a search request with NetEase Cloud Music's API. I have found the URL used for sending a search request over `POST` which is: `http://music.163.com/api/search/get/web` with x-www-form-urlencoded data: `hlpretag=%3Cspan+class%3D%22s-fc56%22%3E&hlposttag=%3C%2Fspan%3E&s=ruslana&type=1&offset=0&total=false&limit=10`.

Sending this request over produces a result like so:

```
{"result":"35b1748964afb6f6ab00803a07621642b1748964af8a7c1d883e3a6f3c773b3d42235da0ba9784a095beda502ab3e8b43fa71f6d6351854d2abf366ed520854009da31982d912f2f7dd26d69e2de683db1f5a185c8d2e83989d1c4b2c230a8669602ea79ebf70989a5b17264db4dabc8072d65deb133001e1236fd8bb37f850490980a4ed65fb639d5629556eff966c2b187d161ba859c63af417aaa447121564e8a4221525d5f0ac885a70ead44a613a07451cddfed5557af6572390e346375e6a91379f94b8530d942573735179b7bdadd3738e4e298e853ded86951b36d7e68ae593ebc6cad73d4e694d2c8debe3e162f84051dda75f10ff58521eb5d5bbf788a1603da61ded1d0b319e80d4bc73218e93665dd8559e420cdd7a0e74d443cd53b8dc20af99a89b3c14e64d9f9aadfc9cbb0b09db8c150e3ea793a1705fb710806ec39f24283c08489169c97527bafb59baed5215f769c55968829b222b3d320b11aab298da17104ddde48d9a77937a6ff100d5e12928d8917810338a51ebf2ef18c879c10a5b2d9c8f29d7524e70265d96ec9016be793f2bbbe55ec7994bb156a6baeda5c4884e6931731d8e6c0124ab298b518977c54c77cbb0eb601db25807ed2ac0d2eff3852427acd83ba0b38dda735b221467975b957074766912e6ea2b2791020bc4305489df1bb9880b47396d1716d01cff904ce4de0d20a4924e6ff220412dbe8305056463c35f7d22dafa3badffded51ee81b6045f5179f59166ec7f4115ecb5f9bb95e92c870a7f7045f1e7765bed3dbf62a09e963279a8ecb2316e39e2540bbe640b20a29a3098f5918aec7572f49ebcca1a3ae96b31927c2274d39ce6b26dd50d0431666a48649c37764010dc48156980022668fd2cec7b855e3a570464a077ffd1005553fd213111a98c2cb20ce50c59c350695b6c93519fd58ee0464e3ae5744873f1de490b0d6f308d6b05cbe59501028a8c8bd6f9a72d1ea6eae2b3ff4a451dc8413d25d611620f3a40b51019a36c2d2674a610bb2cfd2097c1ff3a91ee3b0b6262102dafc72dfd48ab398dea09e3a5d98c952c6674df981017954d222df1cf422403f032cd441f690be826593a50dbac35cb10b555f440e244b1e84e312f9fc0a4b8f5817a916fa4cb65487a12a4558d1adfa01017c6af5f16e2f9eded9c6bab1f62627fa3b3a313a89eeda80f7f4c408542d14ab3d333c0f915d552aedef29595e692dde790dd3b59de48434ff0d86ea13704fbc6f1c8720e82ee2a319d3b779989337239a8","code":200,"abroad":true}
```

I have cut off most of `result` due to it being colossal. What is the data in `result` and how is it encoded? Looking through other peoples efforts turns up nothing to contribute either. On [this](https://github.com/grasses/NetEase-Wireless-MusicBox/blob/master/api.py) Github project I've found there's a function for searches, it doesn't seem to do anything significant to the returned data:

```
 def search(self, s, stype=1, offset=0, total='true', limit=60):
        action = 'http://music.163.com/api/search/get/web' 
        print self.cookies
        data = {
            's': s,
            'type': stype,
            'offset': offset,
            'total': total,
            'limit': 60,
            '__csrf': self.cookies['__csrf'],
        }
        return self.httpRequest('POST', action, data)
```

And when you look on the NetEase website itself and look at the API calls after a search, theres nothing, so its not like theres an extra API call involved in getting all the search data either.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reverse engineering [the client](http://music.163.com/#/download) to determine how it decodes `result`?

Comment: Decompiled the Android app and it doesnt return any significant findings. I have also been looking at other peoples projects that use the search API call and it too doesnt look like any thing significant goes on...Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is embarrassingly simple. Simply remove the `/web` part of the URL so you end up with something like this: `http://music.163.com/api/search/get/` and you're good to go.